# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Get current view's name (Razor .cshtml side)

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am a student and quite new to ASP.NET MVC and I come from ASP.NET Web Form. (Used to it)

I got a list :

```
<ul class="sidebar bg-grayDark">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
            <span class="mif-home icon"></span>
            <span class="title">Home</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="bg-hover-black">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Product")">
            <span class="mif-shop icon"></span>
            <span class="title">Products</span>
            <span class="counter">14</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="bg-hover-black">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Category")">
            <span class="mif-flow-cascade icon"></span>
            <span class="title">Categories</span>
            <span class="counter">9</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="bg-hover-black">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "User")">
            <span class="mif-users icon"></span>
            <span class="title">Users</span>
            <span class="counter">1</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My goal : 
By which view is rendered, I want to add "active" to the  that has been clicked on.
Example : I click on "Category", then Home loses his active class and Category has "active" added to his class. (and the reverse thing with *"bg-hover-black"*)

I thought I could do it by checking the view actually rendered but I don't know how to do it. (I don't know how to check the actual view rendered, but using Razor to check conditions is okay)

I tried with JavaScript first :

```
    $(function () {
        $('.sidebar').on('click', 'li', function () {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
                $('.sidebar li').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        })
    })
```

But it doesn't work because when the page loads, the html is re-rendered with "active" for the Home part. (If I remove "active" for Home, then nothing will be active onClick, except between click and page load).

Have you any solution ? I searched a lot on the web but found nothing to help me.

Sorry for any english mistakes, I'm still learning it :).

Thanks,

Hellcat8.

Comment: The beginning of the post doesn't show.. Here it is :
"Hello everybody,

I am a student and quite new to ASP.NET MVC[...]"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since you are using the convention where your page is named after the controller you can do this in razor to get the controller/page name:

```
@{
 var pageName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
}

<ul class="sidebar bg-grayDark">
    <li class="@(pageName == "Home" ? "active" : "")">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
            <span class="mif-home icon"></span>
            <span class="title">Home</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="bg-hover-black @(pageName == "Product" ? "active" : "")">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Product")">
            <span class="mif-shop icon"></span>
            <span class="title">Products</span>
            <span class="counter">14</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="bg-hover-black @(pageName == "Category" ? "active" : "")">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Category")">
            <span class="mif-flow-cascade icon"></span>
            <span class="title">Categories</span>
            <span class="counter">9</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="bg-hover-black @(pageName == "User" ? "active" : "")">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "User")">
            <span class="mif-users icon"></span>
            <span class="title">Users</span>
            <span class="counter">1</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This will set your active class on the page server side removing the need to do this client side with javascript.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It is working ! :) One more thing : do you have some links where I can have some informations about Razor possibilities ? 
On the web, I only find basics things like IF and Foreach etc.. :(

Thanks again !

Comment: this is wrong, you get the controller name, not the view name as per OP

Comment: @MatthewLock hence the wording in the answer: "Since you are using the convention where your page is named after the controller you can do this"

Comment: I think a semi-colon goes after the top C# snippet.

Answer (score 8):

Here is my approach for a cascaded Bootstrap dropdown submenu, decorated with `active` classes in the _layout.cshtml file of a Razor Pages project.

Major elements of this solution:

- Get the current page route from `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["page"]`.
- Use Anchor Tag Helpers instead of `@Url.Action()`.

Code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    @{
        String pageRoute = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["page"].ToString();
    }
    <li class="dropdown @( pageRoute.Contains("/CustomerModel/") ? "active" : "" )">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Customer-Model <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="@( pageRoute.Contains("/Customers/") ? "active" : "" )"><a asp-page="/CustomerModel/Customers/Index">Customers</a></li>
            <li class="@( pageRoute.Contains("/Partners/")  ? "active" : "" )"><a asp-page="/CustomerModel/CustomerPermissions/Index">CustomerPermissions</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown @( pageRoute.Contains("/StaffModel/") ? "active" : "" )">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Staff-Model <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="@( pageRoute.Contains("/Staff/")              ? "active" : "" )"><a asp-page="/StaffModel/Staff/Index">Staff</a></li>
            <li class="@( pageRoute.Contains("/StaffGroups/")        ? "active" : "" )"><a asp-page="/StaffModel/StaffGroups/Index">StaffGroups</a></li>
            <li class="@( pageRoute.Contains("/PermissionsGroups/")  ? "active" : "" )"><a asp-page="/StaffModel/PermissionsGroups/Index">PermissionsGroups</a></li>
            <li class="@( pageRoute.Contains("/AllowedModules/")     ? "active" : "" )"><a asp-page="/StaffModel/AllowedModules/Index">AllowedModules</a></li>
            <li class="@( pageRoute.Contains("/AllowedServices/")    ? "active" : "" )"><a asp-page="/StaffModel/AllowedServices/Index">AllowedServices</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

To get the name of the active action or controller use the following

```
var controllerName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
var actionName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
```

and then you can give the class for a li using the following code:

```
<li class="@(actionName == "HomePage" ? "active":"")"><a href="~/Account/HomePage">Home</a></li>
```

or you can check both of them as following:

```
 <li class="@(controllerName =="Account" && actionName == "HomePage" ? "active":"")"><a href="~/Account/HomePage">Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

To confirm: You're changing the page when the user clicks on the item.

Because of this, your javascript will run, but then the whole page is re-written and you're back to the first state (ie with Home active as that's in the markup).

To check the current page, you can use `location.href` and compare it with the href url, something like:

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.sidebar>li").removeClass("active");  // or just not have active in the markup
    $("li>a[href=" + location.href + "]").closest("li").addClass("active");
});
```

Alternatively, and this would be more robust, you could pass a token (string, enum or const) in with the viewmodel and check that, eg:

```
<ul class='sidebar'>
    <li data-page='home'...
    ...
    <li data-page='categories'...
```

then

```
$(function() { 
    $("li[data-page=@Model.PageName]").addClass("active")
```

(or just in the markup...)

```
    <li data-page='categories' @(Model.PageName == 'Categories' ? "class=active" : "")>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for spending time to help me ! :)